# How do i display imported dataframe in new Tkinter window?

Tags: python, dataframe, tkinter, initialization

So, I'm currently creating a program to do machine learning on basic excel data. But I'm running into a problem of how to display my dataframe after importing it.

Basically, I need to have a button on the page/window, "PageOutlier" called "Dataframe", which prompts a new window which displays my current dataframe and is updated with the newest information from the "open_file()" function.

The problem I'm running into is:

1. How to create a new (popup) window within this way of initializing frames?
2. How to best display possible loaded/read dataframes in this new window?
3. How to make sure the displayed dataframe in this new window is the newest one from running the function, "open_file()"?

I've tried seaching stackoverflow and various other sources, but can't seem to find a way where it displays the newest dataframe, so I'm hoping somebody has a solution to this.

Dummy data can be all excel files with numeric values which fits into the "open_file()" function.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo, showwarning, askquestion
from tkinter import OptionMenu
from tkinter import StringVar

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import sklearn.cluster as cluster
import scipy.spatial.distance as sdist
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sn

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

RANDOM_STATE = 42 #used to help randomly select the data points
LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)
low_memory=False

df = None
df_nan = None
df_r = None
check_transformer = None
df_output = None

#f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
#a = f.add_subplot(111)

def Credits():
    showinfo("INFO", 
             '''
━━━━━━•❍•°•❍•°•❍•━━━━━━
Goodbye & have a nice day!          
 ━━━━━•❍•°•❍•°•❍•━━━━━━
             ''')
    app.destroy()
    
def RunUC():
    showwarning("Warning", "Under construction")

def open_file():
    global df, df_nan, df_r, df_output, best_n_clusters
    
    df = None
    df_nan = None
    df_r = None
    check_transformer = None
    df_output = None
    ClusterNum = None
    C_Number = None
    name = askopenfilename()

    if name:
        df = pd.read_excel(name, sep=';')
        showinfo("INFO", "DataFrame created")

def Resetter():
    global df, df_nan, df_r, df_output, ClusterNum, check_transformer
    
    df = None
    df_nan = None
    df_r = None
    check_transformer = None
    df_output = None
    ClusterNum = None
    showinfo("INFO", "Dataframe reset")        
        
def NaNifier():
    global df, df_nan
    
    df_nan = None
    
    if df is None:
        showwarning("Warning", "Read file first")
    else:
        df_nan = df
        df_nan.replace(np.nan, 0, inplace=True)
        showinfo("INFO", "Blank values replaced by zero values")
        
def data_remover():
    global df_nan, df_r
    
    if df is None:
        #print("Read file first")
        showwarning("Warning", "Read file first")
    elif df_nan is None:
        #print("Read file first")
        showwarning("Warning", "Replace blank values first")
    elif df_r is not None:
        showwarning("Warning", "Data already cleaned")
    else:
        for y in df_nan.columns:
            if df_nan[y].dtype != np.float64:
                df_r = df_nan.select_dtypes(include=['float64', 'int64'])
                
            elif df_nan[y].dtype != np.int64:
                df_r = df_nan.select_dtypes(include=['float64', 'int64'])
                
            else:
                df_r = df_nan
                
        showinfo("INFO", "Data cleaned")

def MM_data_transformer():
    
    global df, df_nan, df_r, check_transformer
    
    MM_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    
    if df is None:
        showwarning("Warning", "Read file first")
    elif df_nan is None:
        showwarning("Warning", "Replace blank values first")
    elif df_r is None:
        showwarning("Warning", "Clean data first")
    elif check_transformer is not None:
        showwarning("Warning", "Data already transformed")
    else:
        check_transformer = 1337 # Check to see if data is transformed
        df_r = df_r.astype(float)
        df_r = pd.DataFrame(MM_scaler.fit_transform(df_r),columns = df_r.columns) #Scaling data
        df_r = df_r.round(2) #Rounding data
        print(df_r)
        showinfo("INFO", "Data scaled")

def S_data_transformer():
    
    global df, df_nan, df_r, check_transformer
    
    S_scaler = StandardScaler()
    
    if df is None:
        showwarning("Warning", "Read file first")
    elif df_nan is None:
        showwarning("Warning", "Replace blank values first")
    elif df_r is None:
        showwarning("Warning", "Clean data first")
    elif check_transformer is not None:
        showwarning("Warning", "Data already transformed")
    else:
        check_transformer = 1337 # Check to see if data is transformed
        df_r = df_r.astype(float)
        df_r = pd.DataFrame(S_scaler.fit_transform(df_r),columns = df_r.columns) #Scaling data
        df_r = df_r.round(2) #Rounding data
        print(df_r)
        showinfo("INFO", "Data scaled")

def RunSilHou():
    #Silhouette Score for further clustering
    global df, df_nan, df_r, df_output, ClusterNum
    
    ClusterNum = None
    
    if df is None:
        showwarning("Warning", "Read file first")
    elif df_nan is None:
        showwarning("Warning", "Replace blank values first")
    elif df_r is None:
        showwarning("WARNING", "Clean file first")
    elif df_output is not None:
        showwarning("WARNING", "Already computed KMeans")
    else:
        n_samples, n_features = df_r.shape
        procent_samples = n_samples
        #procent_samples = n_samples*0.10 #10% of the dataset for sample_size
        procent_samples = int(procent_samples)

        sil_score_max = -1 #this is the minimum possible score

        for n_clusters in range(2,10):
          model = KMeans(n_clusters = n_clusters, n_jobs = 8, init='k-means++', max_iter=100, n_init=1)
          labels = model.fit_predict(df_r)
          sil_score = silhouette_score(df_r, labels, sample_size = procent_samples, random_state = RANDOM_STATE)
          print("The average silhouette score for %i clusters is %0.10f" %(n_clusters, sil_score))
          if sil_score > sil_score_max:
            sil_score_max = sil_score
            ClusterNum = n_clusters
            Cluster_text = "Silhouette Score calculated %i clusters" %(ClusterNum)
        showinfo(title="Results", message=Cluster_text)
        
def RunKM_clustering():

    global df, df_nan, df_r, df_output, ClusterNum

    if df is None:
        showwarning("Warning", "Read file first")
    elif df_nan is None:
        showwarning("Warning", "Replace blank values first")
    elif df_r is None:
        showwarning("WARNING", "Clean file first")
    elif df_output is not None:
        showwarning("WARNING", "Already computed KMeans")
    else:       
        df_output = df
        kmeans = cluster.KMeans(n_jobs = 8, n_clusters = ClusterNum, init = 'k-means++', random_state = RANDOM_STATE).fit(df_r)

        centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
        dists = pd.DataFrame(
            sdist.cdist(df_r, centroids), 
            columns=['dist_{}'.format(i) for i in range(len(centroids))],
            index=df_output.index)
        df_output = pd.concat([df_r, dists], axis=1)
        
        df_output['cluster_number'] = kmeans.labels_
        
        df_output_columns = df_output.filter(regex=('dist_')).columns

        df_output['dists'] = df_output[df_output_columns].min(axis=1)

        df_output = df_output[df_output.columns.drop(list(df_output.filter(regex='dist_')))]

        showinfo("INFO", "KMeans clusters Calculated")

def RunKM_outlier():

    global df, df_nan, df_r, df_output
    
    if df is None:
        showwarning("Warning", "Read file first")
    elif df_nan is None:
        showwarning("Warning", "Replace blank values first")
    elif df_r is None:
        showwarning("WARNING", "Clean file first")
    elif df_output is not None:
        kmeans_one = cluster.KMeans(n_jobs = 8, n_clusters = 1, init = 'k-means++', random_state = RANDOM_STATE).fit(df_r)

        centroids = kmeans_one.cluster_centers_
        dist = pd.DataFrame(
            sdist.cdist(df_r, centroids), 
            columns=['dist_clust_outlier'.format(i) for i in range(len(centroids))],
            index=df_output.index)
        df_output = pd.concat([df_output, dist], axis=1)
    else:    
        df_output = df
        kmeans_one = cluster.KMeans(n_jobs = 8, n_clusters = 1, init = 'k-means++', random_state = RANDOM_STATE).fit(df_r)

        centroids = kmeans_one.cluster_centers_
        dist = pd.DataFrame(
            sdist.cdist(df_r, centroids), 
            columns=['dist_clust_outlier'.format(i) for i in range(len(centroids))],
            index=df_output.index)
        df_output = pd.concat([df_output, dist], axis=1)

def RunIsoForest():
    
    global df, df_nan, df_r, df_output, ContNum
    
    if df is None:
        showwarning("Warning", "Read file first")
    elif df_nan is None:
        showwarning("Warning", "Replace blank values first")
    elif df_r is None:
        showwarning("WARNING", "Clean file first")
    elif ContNum is None:
        showwarning('Warning', "Define Contamination Value")
    elif df_output is not None:
        iso_columns = df_r.columns
        clf = IsolationForest(max_samples="auto", n_jobs=-1, random_state=RANDOM_STATE, behaviour="new", contamination=ContNum)

        clf.fit(df_r[iso_columns])

        iso_pred = clf.predict(df_r[iso_columns])

        df_output['isolation_class'] = iso_pred
        showinfo("INFO", "IsolationForest Calculated")
    else:  
        df_output = df
        
        iso_columns = df_r.columns
        clf = IsolationForest(max_samples="auto", n_jobs=-1, random_state=RANDOM_STATE, behaviour="new", contamination=ContNum)

        clf.fit(df_r[iso_columns])

        iso_pred = clf.predict(df_r[iso_columns])

        df_output['isolation_class'] = iso_pred
        showinfo("INFO", "IsolationForest Calculated")

def save_in_new_file():

    global df, df_nan, df_r, df_output

    if df is None:
        showwarning("Warning", "Read file first")
    elif df_nan is None:
        showwarning("Warning", "Replace blank values first")
    elif df_r is None:
        showwarning("WARNING", "Clean file first")
    elif df_output is None:
        showwarning("WARNING", "Compute file first")
    else:
        df_output.to_csv("output.csv", sep=';', index=0, mode='w')
        showinfo("INFO", "DataFrame saved")

def ClusterDefinition():
    
    global ClusterNum
    
    ClusterNum = Clus_Number.get()
    ClusterNum = int(ClusterNum)
    print(ClusterNum)
    Cluster_text = "KMeans clustering set to %i clusters" %(ClusterNum)
    showinfo(title="Results", message=Cluster_text)

def ContaminationDefinition():
    
    global ContNum
    
    ContNum = Cont_Number.get()
    ContNum = int(ContNum)
    ContNum = ContNum/100 # to return integer to 0.0X state
    print(ContNum)
    Contamination_text = "Contamination value set to %0.2f" %(ContNum)
    showinfo(title="Results", message=Contamination_text)


class Mainapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        
        #tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default="iconimage_kmeans.ico") #Icon for program
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Advanched analytics")
        
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        menubar = tk.Menu(container)
        filemenu_file = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu_file.add_command(label="Open", command=open_file)
        filemenu_file.add_command(label="Save", command=save_in_new_file)
        filemenu_file.add_separator()
        filemenu_file.add_command(label="Exit", command=Credits)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu_file)
        
        filemenu_edit = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        submenu_t = tk.Menu(container, tearoff=0)
        submenu_s = tk.Menu(container, tearoff=0)
        submenu_t.add_command(label="Blank values", command=NaNifier)
        submenu_t.add_command(label="Non-numeric values", command=data_remover)
        submenu_s.add_command(label="MinMax scaler", command=MM_data_transformer)
        submenu_s.add_command(label="Standard scaler", command=S_data_transformer)
        filemenu_edit.add_cascade(label='Data transformating', menu=submenu_t, underline=0)
        filemenu_edit.add_cascade(label='Data scaling', menu=submenu_s, underline=0)
        filemenu_edit.add_separator()
        filemenu_edit.add_command(label="Clear dataframe", command=Resetter)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=filemenu_edit)    
        
        filemenu_help = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu_help.add_command(label="Function descriptions", command=RunUC) # Make help txt. file
        filemenu_help.add_command(label="Data cleaning steps", command=RunUC)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=filemenu_help)
        
        tk.Tk.config(self, menu=menubar)
        
        self.frames = {} 
        
        for F in (StartPage, PageCluster, PageOutlier, PageElbow, DataPage):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
        
class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text=
                         "Advanched analytics", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Clustering", 
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageCluster))
        button1.pack(fill='x')
        
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Outlier Detection", 
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOutlier))
        button2.pack(fill='x')

class PageCluster(tk.Frame):    

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Clustering", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10) 
        
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text='Run Silhouette Score Calculation', command=RunSilHou)
        button1.pack(fill='x')
        
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Elbow Method Calculation",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageElbow))
        button2.pack(fill='x')
        
        button3 = ttk.Button(self, text='Run KMeans', command=RunKM_clustering)
        button3.pack(fill='x')
        
        button4 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button4.pack(fill='x')    
        
class PageElbow(tk.Frame):    

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Elbow Method", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10) 
        
        global ClusterNum, C_Number

        def RunElbowMethod():
            f = None
            f = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
            wcss = []
            for i in range(1, 11):
                kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = i, init = 'k-means++', random_state = RANDOM_STATE)
                kmeans.fit(df)
                wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)
            plt.plot(range(1, 11), wcss)
            plt.title('The Elbow Method')
            plt.xlabel('Number of clusters')
            plt.ylabel('WCSS')
            plt.draw()
          
            canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
            canvas.draw()
            canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

            toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, self)
            toolbar.update()
            canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        ClusterOptions = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
        Clus_Number = StringVar(self)
        Clus_Number.set(ClusterOptions[0]) # default value

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Run Elbow Method", command=RunElbowMethod)
        button1.pack(fill='x')
        
        dropdown1 = tk.OptionMenu(self, Clus_Number, *ClusterOptions)
        dropdown1.pack()
            
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Define Number of Clusters", command=ClusterDefinition)
        button2.pack(fill='x')
        
        button3 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageCluster))
        button3.pack(fill='x')
        
        
class PageOutlier(tk.Frame):    

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Outlier Detection", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)            
        
        global ContNum, Cont_Number
        
        ContOptions = np.arange(1, 100, 1)
        Cont_Number = StringVar(self)
        Cont_Number.set(ContOptions[0]) # default value
        
        dropdown1 = tk.OptionMenu(self, Cont_Number, *ContOptions)
        dropdown1.pack()
            
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Define Contamination Value (0.X Decimals)", command=ContaminationDefinition)
        button2.pack(fill='x')
        
        button3 = ttk.Button(self, text='Run IsolationForest Outlier Detection', command=RunIsoForest)
        button3.pack(fill='x')
        
        button4 = ttk.Button(self, text='Dataframe', command=RunUC)
        button4.pack(fill='x')
        
        button5 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button5.pack(fill='x')
        
        
app = Mainapp()
app.geometry('500x400')
app.mainloop()
#app.destroy()
```

Comment: Please reduce this to a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). All you need is a small dummy df (perhaps produced with `df.head(5)` with the barebones of the gui.

Comment: Also, please avoid asking several questions at once or your question might be closed because it needs more focus.

Comment: If you look at the questions, they feed into each other. It is basically open a new window with a kind of refresh/frame destruction and re-creation. I just can't seem to find how to do it.

So I mainly split it up to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself by combine some answers from around stackoverflow.
Basically creating a new window through a function instead of my "normal" framework and then creating a button with command=DisplayDF. This makes sure it sees only the newest dataframe and does not create error when being called, due to being referenced before being imported.

```
def DisplayDF():

    global df
    # create child window
    win = Toplevel()
    # display message
    message = "Current output (Max 100 rows)"
    tk.Label(win, text=message).pack()
    text = tk.Text(win)
    text.insert(tk.END, str(df.head(100)))
    text.pack()
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a demo below with comments on how to do this. In the code below i create a class called ExcelWindow that inherits from tk.Toplevel, this will open a new window. I also pass a DataFrame parameter inside this class. The once the Treeview Widget inside the ExcelWindow is created it will insert your dataframe into it. Thus allowing you to view the dataframe inside a new window. You can open as many windows as you want with different files too!

To demo the code below create a excel file (.xlsx) on your PC with the following data:
[image]

Then run the code below and click to browse button. once you have clicked on the file in windows explorer click on the "load file" button and a new Tkinter window with your excel data should appear. As mentioned before all comments are in the code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox, ttk

import pandas as pd
# a video tutorial for a similar question can be found here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PgLjwl6Br0k
# initalise the tkinter GUI
root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry("500x500") # set the root dimensions
root.pack_propagate(False) # tells the root to not let the widgets inside it determine its size.
root.resizable(0, 0) # makes the root window fixed in size.

# Frame for open file dialog
file_frame = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="Open File")
file_frame.place(height=100, width=400, rely=0.65, relx=0)

# Buttons
button1 = tk.Button(file_frame, text="Browse A File", command=lambda: File_dialog())
button1.place(rely=0.65, relx=0.50)

button2 = tk.Button(file_frame, text="Load File", command=lambda: Load_excel_data())
button2.place(rely=0.65, relx=0.30)

# The file/file path text
label_file = ttk.Label(file_frame, text="No File Selected")
label_file.place(rely=0, relx=0)

# this will open the windows explorer so you can select your file
def File_dialog():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/",
                                          title="Select A File",
                                          filetype=(("xlsx files", "*.xlsx"),("All Files", "*.*")))
    label_file["text"] = filename
    return None

# this will load your excel file into the excel window
def Load_excel_data():
    file_path = label_file["text"]  # get the text from the path you provided
    try:
        excel_filename = r"{}".format(file_path)
        if excel_filename[-4:] == ".csv": # if its a csv file use read_csv
            df = pd.read_csv(excel_filename)
        else:  # otherwise use read_excel
            df = pd.read_excel(excel_filename)

    except ValueError:
        tk.messagebox.showerror("Information", "The file you have chosen is invalid")
        return None
    except FileNotFoundError:
        tk.messagebox.showerror("Information", f"No such file as {file_path}")
        return None
    # pass the dataframe into the class ExcelWindow
    ExcelWindow(df)


class ExcelWindow(tk.Toplevel): # Inherits from tk.Toplevel

    def __init__(self, your_dataframe): # the dataframe you passed through is here
        super().__init__()

        # Frame for TreeView
        frame1 = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Excel Data")
        frame1.pack(fill="both", expand="true")
        frame1.pack_propagate(0)

        # the size of the window.
        self.geometry("500x500")
        self.resizable(0, 0)
        self.title("Your Excel File in Tkinter") # the window title

        # This creates your Treeview widget.
        tv1 = ttk.Treeview(frame1)
        tv1.place(relheight=1, relwidth=1) # set the height and width of the widget to 100% of its container (frame1).

        treescrolly = tk.Scrollbar(frame1, orient="vertical", command=tv1.yview) # command means update the yaxis view of the widget
        treescrollx = tk.Scrollbar(frame1, orient="horizontal", command=tv1.xview) # command means update the xaxis view of the widget
        tv1.configure(xscrollcommand=treescrollx.set, yscrollcommand=treescrolly.set) # assign the scrollbars to the Treeview Widget
        treescrollx.pack(side="bottom", fill="x") # make the scrollbar fill the x axis of the Treeview widget
        treescrolly.pack(side="right", fill="y") # make the scrollbar fill the y axis of the Treeview widget


        # this loads the dataframe into the treeview widget
        tv1["column"] = list(your_dataframe.columns)
        tv1["show"] = "headings"
        for column in tv1["columns"]:
            tv1.heading(column, text=column) # let the column heading = column name

        df_rows = your_dataframe.to_numpy().tolist() # turns the dataframe into a list of lists
        for row in df_rows:
            tv1.insert("", "end", values=row) # inserts each list into the treeview. For parameters see https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Treeview.insert


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I like what you have done, but it seems hard to combine with the way my current framework is setup. But I have found an answer, so many thanks for taking the time. It is appreciated!